# How to properly filter an image using OpenCV? To read and extract the text with the highest possible percentage of effectiveness

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

This is what I do, I take some images and some of them contain information that I need. Being these the images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

- How do I find that information? I use a template that contains two symbols (Euro and Dollar), when this symbols are found in any of the images, then I can process the image and try to extract the data that I need.

[image: Euro and Dollar Symbols (The template we will use)]

- How do I extract the data? I take the dimensions of the found match, and since I know that the information to extract will always be contained to the right of the match, I dimension a box towards the right edge of my image, with which I make sure I have a box with the data to extract.

[image: Section with the data I need]

Here is the code, I will divide it into several sections to explain the process a little better:

###### 1) Initial Settings for the Code (Imports, a list of images which will be processed, a couple of functions to filter the image and finally the configuration set for reading data from Tesseract):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

imagenes = ["monitor1.jpg", "monitor2.jpg", "monitor3.jpg"]

# get grayscale image
def get_grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Noise Removal (This is the filter I am using)
def remove_noise(image):
    return cv2.medianBlur(image,5)

# The configuration we will use to read the images:
my_config = r"--psm 11 --oem 3"
```

###### 2) Next, the template with which we will try to match is read and we take its dimensions (w=width and h=height).

###### We present the methods to find the matches and enter a loop reviewing image by image, trying to find a matching image:

```
# Reading the Template (Euro and Dollar):
# template_simbolo = cv2.imread('template_euro_dolar.jpg', 0)
template = cv2.imread('template_simbolos.jpg', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

# The methods we will use to find the matchs (This should be a list of 6 methods
# but working with a big list of images it takes an eternity, so we will only
# use one by now for the tests) :
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF']

# A loop where we are going to filter every image, find the matchs if there are
# and extract the data:
for img in imagenes:
    print("**************************")
    # Image to read:
    img_rgb = cv2.imread(img)

    # The image filtered in gray:
    gray = get_grayscale(img_rgb)
    img_gray = remove_noise(gray)

    # With res we will find the matches but we only take the accurate ones (80% or more)    
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

    print(loc)
    print(len(loc[0]))
```

###### 3) In this part of the code, first we enclose the match in a box, we filter the original image, and we look for the coordinates of the match, once this is done, we proceed to enclose in a box the section where the desired information is found.

```
    # If loc contains values ​​it is because there is a match:
    if len(loc[0]) > 0:
        print("Match Found")
        # We enclose the found matches in a box and save the result:
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imwrite('res_monitor.png', img_rgb)

        # A loop of matching methods:
        for meth in methods:

            # We filter the image and change it to a gray color
            gray = get_grayscale(img_rgb)
            img_gray = remove_noise(gray)

            # We evaluate the method to use and according to it we have some
            # default coordinates
            method = eval(meth)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            print("min_val:", min_val)
            print("max_val:", max_val)
            print("min_loc:", min_loc)
            print("max_loc:", max_loc)

            # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
            if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
                top_left = min_loc
            else:
                top_left = max_loc

            # To know the bottom right coordinate, we respectively take the value
            # of top_left and add the width w and height h to know this coordinate.
            w, h = template.shape[::-1]
            bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
            print("top_left:", top_left)
            print("bottom_right:", bottom_right)
            print("x:", top_left[0])
            print("y:", top_left[1])

            # Now, in our original image, which we previously filtered, we will
            # place a box or rectangle according to the dimensions established 
            # before. (top_left and bottom_right)
            w, h = img_gray.shape[::-1]
            print("w:", w)
            print("h:", bottom_right[1])
            cv2.rectangle(img_gray, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
            imagen = cv2.rectangle(img_gray, top_left, (w, bottom_right[1]), 255, 2)
            x = top_left[0]
            y = top_left[1]
            w = w
            h = bottom_right[1]

            # Finally we crop this section of the code where we established the area
            # to review and with pytesseract we look for the data that we can obtain
            # from said cropped image.
            crop_image = img_gray[y:h, x:w]
            cv2.imwrite("croped.jpg", crop_image)
            data = pytesseract.image_to_data(crop_image, config=my_config,
                                             output_type=Output.DICT)
            print(data, "\n")
```

###### 4) Finally we create a dictionary to save the rate of the euro and the dollar, if everything goes well they will be saved correctly.

At the end of this process, a plot is shown to verify that the information was extracted correctly.

```
            # We create a dictionary to store the values ​​of Euro and Dollar
            i = 0
            currencies= {}
            for value in data["text"]:
                print(value)
                try:
                    currency= value.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")
                    currency= float(currency)
                    i = i + 1
                    if i == 1:
                        currencies["Euro"] = currency
                    elif i == 2 and currency< currencies["Euro"]:
                        currencies["Dolar"] = currency

                except: ValueError


            # We pass the image to string to obtain the rates of the currencies
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop_image, config = my_config)
            print(text) 
            print(currencies)

            # We graph the results and confirm that the data extraction and the
            # demarcated area are correct.
            plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res, cmap = 'gray')
            plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
            plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap = 'gray')
            plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
            plt.suptitle(meth)
            plt.show()

    else:
        print("DOES NOT MATCH")
```

## The results:

With the code and all the logic presented above, it usually works very well on these images, but for some reason sometimes it doesn't read the image properly, it doesn't save the information in the desired way.

[image]

As can be seen, the area that the code takes is the desired one, but the currency dictionary does not record any information:
[image]

Which is strange because if I run the code on a longer list of images, that same image is recognized perfectly.

So the problem here is that sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't, and I'm not quite sure why. Does anyone know what I can polish? What am I doing wrong? Any advice?

Comment: What debugging did you do?  Where does it fail? Are there any error messages?

Comment: question needs a _lot_ more focus. please review [ask]. and perhaps https://idownvotedbecau.se/